# Would increasing ram from 4gb to 8 gb help i,prove running of high fps games in core i3 fourth gen?

Tags: memory

I have intel core(TM) i3-4010 4gb ram laptop 
i run pubg and it but it lags would increasing my ram from 4gb to 8gb help?

Comment: Probably.  The real issue will probably be your video card and related drivers.

Comment: i know graphics card issues the most but i was wondering if increasing ram would help to some extent or not?

Comment: It may well help. 4gb is on the very low end of RAM levels these days.  After a fresh reboot, let your desktop, etc. load and check your task manager, etc. and see how much free RAM you have.  Then consider that you are going to load a bunch of stuff into RAM (graphics, textures, models, sounds, etc) and then do a lot of processing on it (which requires moving and copying data around, using more RAM).  If you have to swap out to disk, it will be slower, simply because of amount of time needed to do it all.  More RAM will make your overall computing experience better. Go for it.